# What xsd shema gwt modules use?

Tags: java, xml, gwt, xsd

The [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html) contains mane examples, but no one with `xsd` attribute for xml schema. Something tells me that they validate xml before parsing, but what shema do they use?

Comment: Why closing? Could you please add a comment?

Answer (score 0):

There's **no** validation in the sense of XMLSchema or DTD validation, validation is done by the code that makes use of the information and "maps" it to internal data structure.

The GWT Project provides a DTD to help IDEs do autocompletion, but the DTD is **not** used by GWT itself (and as result, it might be out of sync, with documents that don't validate but will be accepted by GWT). I'd thus recommend not using the DTD for anything else than what it's designed for: providing help with autocompletion, but **not** validation.

Comment: By the way where such DTD can be dowloaded?